# How to solve ASM Instrumentation process wasn't able to resolve some classes?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I build the app
`./gradlew assembleRelease`
then I get this warning:

```
ASM Instrumentation process wasn't able to resolve some classes, this means that
the instrumented classes might contain corrupt stack frames. Make sure the
dependencies that contain these classes are on the runtime or the provided
classpath. Otherwise, the jvm might fail to load the corrupt classes at runtime
when running in a jvm environment like unit tests.

Classes that weren't resolved:
> sun.misc.Unsafe
> androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
> retrofit2.Response
> javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart
> javax.naming.NamingException
> javax.naming.directory.Attributes
```

I'm currently using AGP 8.0.1

In the previous AGP version (7.4.2), the warning was worded differently:

```
Unable to find common super type for java/lang/reflect/Field and sun/misc/Unsafe.
Unable to find common super type for sun/misc/Unsafe and java/lang/Object.
Unable to find common super type for com/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zznt and sun/misc/Unsafe.
Unable to find common super type for androidx/appcompat/view/ContextThemeWrapper and android/content/Context.
Unable to find common super type for com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture and androidx/work/InputMerger.
Unable to find common super type for java/lang/Throwable and retrofit2/Response.
Unable to find common super type for java/lang/Exception and javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.
Unable to find common super type for javax/naming/NamingException and javax/naming/directory/Attributes.
Unable to find common super type for java/lang/Object and javax/naming/directory/Attributes.
Unable to find common super type for java/lang/reflect/Field and sun/misc/Unsafe.
Unable to find common super type for sun/misc/Unsafe and java/lang/Object.
Unable to find common super type for com/google/android/recaptcha/internal/zzjo and sun/misc/Unsafe.
Unable to find common super type for java/lang/reflect/Field and sun/misc/Unsafe.
Unable to find common super type for sun/misc/Unsafe and java/lang/Object.
Unable to find common super type for com/google/android/gms/internal/firebase-auth-api/zzaje and sun/misc/Unsafe.
```

I suspect the message change is related to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231997058 but I still have no idea how to fix this warning

Answer (score 2):

I was the original reporter of this issue and *I think* there's not much to do from your side as a user. Some of the libraries declare their dependencies as `compileOnly` and this warning is printed when ASM instrumentation is trying to resolve types from those `compileOnly` dependencies while they are not present at runtime.

But there's nothing wrong with that per se, if the library declaring `compileOnly` dependency has proper runtime checks to not even call to the classes from that dependency, if it's not present on the classpath.

But I think it might be worth pinging that issue on google tracker because I also think this doesn't make sense to print this warning, especially in the case like

```
Unable to find common super type for sun/misc/Unsafe and java/lang/Object.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been running into this issue as well recently and I have been working to make sure that most of the ones in the list I am adding as dependencies with `implementation` and that has reduced the number down to the last 3 that I have remaining.

```
Classes that weren't resolved:
> sun.misc.Unsafe
> javax.naming.NamingException
> javax.naming.directory.Attributes
```

The others I have searched for the jar files that those classes are found and added them if need. Some are found in libraries that are added to the app and I have added those dependencies as well. Using `minify` will remove any that are not being used and you can keep the ones that are required if `minify` removes them with `proguard` configurations.